# Xamarin.iOS: change height anchor programmatically

Tags: c#, ios, xamarin.ios

I've UIStackView's height whose set to 100 in story board. I'm programmatically adding SubViews in a loop to the StackView. So, I need to change the StackView's height too programmatically

So I tried,

```
summaryStackView.HeightAnchor.ConstraintEqualTo(summaryStackView.HeightAnchor).Active = false;
summaryStackView.HeightAnchor.ConstraintEqualTo(HEIGHT).Active = true;
```

but it doesn't seems to work, and I getting warning in application output.

```
Unable to simultaneously satisfy constraints.
    Probably at least one of the constraints in the following list is one you don't want. 
    Try this: 
        (1) look at each constraint and try to figure out which you don't expect; 
        (2) find the code that added the unwanted constraint or constraints and fix it. 
(
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7d538010 V:[UIStackView:0x7d538460(200)]>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7d48f4a0 V:[UIStackView:0x7d538460(184)]>"
)

Will attempt to recover by breaking constraint 
<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7d538010 V:[UIStackView:0x7d538460(200)]>

Make a symbolic breakpoint at UIViewAlertForUnsatisfiableConstraints to catch this in the debugger.
The methods in the UIConstraintBasedLayoutDebugging category on UIView listed in <UIKit/UIView.h> may also be helpful.
Thread finished: <Thread Pool> #9
Thread finished: <Thread Pool> #7
Thread finished: <Thread Pool> #8
2016-07-30 20:29:20.119 Gogch.iOS[2219:175673] Unable to simultaneously satisfy constraints.
    Probably at least one of the constraints in the following list is one you don't want. 
    Try this: 
        (1) look at each constraint and try to figure out which you don't expect; 
        (2) find the code that added the unwanted constraint or constraints and fix it. 
(
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7d60e9a0 H:[UIView:0x7d60eb50(320)]>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7d2cffd0 'fittingSizeHTarget' H:[UIView:0x7d60eb50(359)]>"
)

Will attempt to recover by breaking constraint 
<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7d2cffd0 'fittingSizeHTarget' H:[UIView:0x7d60eb50(359)]>

Make a symbolic breakpoint at UIViewAlertForUnsatisfiableConstraints to catch this in the debugger.
The methods in the UIConstraintBasedLayoutDebugging category on UIView listed in <UIKit/UIView.h> may also be helpful.
2016-07-30 20:29:20.124 Gogch.iOS[2219:175673] Unable to simultaneously satisfy constraints.
    Probably at least one of the constraints in the following list is one you don't want. 
    Try this: 
        (1) look at each constraint and try to figure out which you don't expect; 
        (2) find the code that added the unwanted constraint or constraints and fix it. 
(
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7d60e9a0 H:[UIView:0x7d60eb50(320)]>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7d4694c0 'fittingSizeHTarget' H:[UIView:0x7d60eb50(359)]>"
)

Will attempt to recover by breaking constraint 
<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7d4694c0 'fittingSizeHTarget' H:[UIView:0x7d60eb50(359)]>

Make a symbolic breakpoint at UIViewAlertForUnsatisfiableConstraints to catch this in the debugger.
The methods in the UIConstraintBasedLayoutDebugging category on UIView listed in <UIKit/UIView.h> may also be helpful.
```

How how do I properly change it?